# Convert xml file to type="xs:hexBinary" using c#

Tags: c#, xml, hex

I am working on a service that i should submit a xml file as byte[]. i converted the xmldocument.outerxml to byte[] and i have also tried some other byte[] convertion methods nothing worked out . now i trying to convert xmldocument.outerxml to type="xs:hexBinary". can anyone Help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

xs:hexBinary is just the hex value of the bytes. Heres how you can do it:

```
// Load up some xml
string xml = "<root><child>value</child></root>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

// Get OuterXml as bytes
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(doc.OuterXml);

// bytes to hex values
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

foreach (byte b in bytes)
    buffer.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);

// Results
Console.WriteLine(buffer);
```

**UPDATE**

After discovering that you need to zip the Xml... To get zip functionality, you will need to add references to **System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll** and **System.IO.Compression.dll**

```
// Load up some xml
string xml = "<root><child>value</child></root>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);


byte[] bytes;

// Create zip
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        // The name of the xml file inside the zip
        var entry = zip.CreateEntry("myxml_file.xml");
        using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
        {
            // Save the xml file into the zip
            doc.Save(stream);
        }
    }

    // Get bytes of zip file
    bytes = ms.GetBuffer();
}

// Save the file to Debug\Bin\out.zip for testing only (remove from final code)
File.WriteAllBytes("out.zip", bytes);

// bytes to hex values
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

foreach (byte b in bytes)
    buffer.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);

// Results
Console.WriteLine(buffer);
```

Comment: sorry Mr.Mike Hixson its not working for me throwing same exception not a zip file.do you know any another methods or ideas.

Comment: Mr.Mike Hixson here string builder is in string format. i have to pass parameter as byte if i again convert this string to byte is it correct way to produce hex byte[].

Comment: I guess Im not sure what you are trying to do. You didnt mention anything about zip files in your original post.

Comment: Sorry Mr.Mike the service needs xml zip file as byte[]

Comment: Updated the code to show how to get the bytes of a zip compressed xml file.